# Dell Latitude E6510 fingerprint reader

Tags: dell-latitude

I've downloaded a number of different drivers from the Dell's support page (i have a valid service tag), but I cannot get the Fingerprinter reader to work in  my environment.

I am able to see the Control Vault w/Fingerprint Swipe Sensor driver listed under:

Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Biometric Devices

When I click on **Use your fingerprint with Windows**, I get the following exception:

> C:Program Files\Broadcom Corporation\Broadcom USH Host
>   Components\BrcmFMA.exe
>
> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side
>   configuration is incorrect...

This error points to the Windows Application event log and this message:

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files\Broadcom
>   Corporation\Broadcom USH Host Components\BrcmFMA.exe". Dependent
>   Assembly
>   Microsoft.VC90.MFC,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"
>   could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

I have yet to locate anything via Google.  I am running Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: This might sound dumb... but are you sure you actually have the fingerprint reader?  I get these all the time and that is not a default option the way we get them (yours could certainly be different).  Either way make sure you also double check your Device Manager to ensure you have no problem components and if you do go get the drivers from the Dell support site.

Comment: Yes, I've used it before. :) I re-installed the OS after a VMWare Workstation uninstall jacked up the networking config on the machine so bad I decided it was not worth troubleshooting and time for a re-build.

Comment: This might be another dumb one... did you go back and remove then freshly install any of the drivers that could be in question that auto recognized and got installed by the OS?  Just a thought... in particular the Chipset Drivers and the Control Vault stuff.

Comment: Well, in this last round of reinstalling I turned off Windows Update completely.  I started by installing the Intel Network driver, downloaded directly from Dell.  I installed all the software and drivers from Dell directly.  I have a case open with Dell.  I just want to know what I must install to get the fingerprint reader working.  I admit, I have not installed everything labeled "Control Vault."  I did install the item labeled something like "Control Vault Security drivers."

Comment: @codewise Were you able to resolve this issue? I have a similar problem when clicking on "Use your fingerprint with Windows". Same OS, same Latitude model, but different error. I am getting the following: "Windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files\Broadcom Corporation\Broadcom USH Host Components\BrcmFMA.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and this is what I did.

Firstly I downloaded [this](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/vn/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=Y2GT8&c=us&l=en&cs=&s=corp) driver and followed the Installation Instructions.

I was then stuck with the same problem you had. After some searching I found [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/error-the-application-has-failed-to-start-because/df019c0d-746e-42d0-ad68-465e18e3f3ef).

I installed the [2008 SP1 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=BA9257CA-337F-4B40-8C14-157CFDFFEE4E&displaylang=enMicrosoft) and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Just a note to say that this fix also worked for me Dell Lattitude E7440 fingerprint driver

Comment: I have Latitude E5450, installing the C++ Redistributable package did help. Thanks!

Comment: Installing the 2008 SP1 Visual C++ Redistributable (x64) package is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem you did on my Dell Precision 6700. I'm currently running Windows 8 Pro 64bit. I loaded the 2008 Visual C+ SP1 redistro package, enabled the fingerprint swipe, and didn't even have to reboot. I upgrade from Win7, so I could run a Virtual Machine of some OSs. Some people choose to download the 25 meg install file. I chose to download all of the system drivers.  That download is 300megs and extracts to a gig and a half.  It appears that the drivers are not dependent on the model.