# Where to get fingerprint scanning software for Dell Latitude E5520?

Tags: windows-7, dell-latitude

Does anyone know the name of a software program that will let me use my fingerprint as a password? I recently had to replace the hard drive in my Dell Latitude E5520, and I don't have the drivers and software disks that came with it. I have visited [Dell support page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/servicetag/F7B1KS1/drivers?s=BSD) and also ran Slim Drivers, but nothing gave me the software I need to actually log in my fingerprint. It has Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, Service pack 1, 4GB RAM, an Intel Core i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz.

Comment: If you upgrade to Windows 8 this feature is built into it.

Comment: I do not wish to upgrade to Windows 8, I would like to keep 7, and have my fingerprint scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Authentec biometric device.

AuthenTec Windows Biometric Framework Integrated Driver View details
AUTHENTEC_WINDOWS--BIOMETRIC_A00_R308120.exe | Hard-Drive (50 MB)
Security |
Release date 7/13/2011
| Last Updated 3/5/2014
| Option

[Dell support](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/latitude-e5520/drivers)

The link is to Dell support for latitude 5520.

Select your OS, I found win 7 64 bit in this sample.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed that. I am having trouble figuring out how to make it an option in user account control on Windows, to use as my login password for the laptop.

Comment: Check out this other Q on the topic. Although the computers are dif. the solution to your part two issue may be found here:http://superuser.com/questions/367688/dell-latitude-e6510-fingerprint-reader

Answer (score 2):

I found the self extractor on Dell's website for the bio-metric coprocessor driver to display the error "corrupt". I used 7zip to manually extract the files and then installed the driver using the Device Manager.

Works with Latitude - D620, D820, D420, D620, D630, D830, D631, XT, D430, ATG D630, D630c, XFR D630;
Precision - M2300, M4300, M6300, M65;
XPS Notebook - M1330, M1530 - TouchChip

Link to Driver - http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER96415M/1/R173506.exe